# Flutter Global Variable value gets set when list is filtered

Tags: flutter, dart, global-variables

was not sure how to phrase this question but am struggeling with the following at the moment. I have a global variable as such:

```
class GlobalVariables{ 
  static List<Activity> globalActivities = [];
}
```

I fill the list initially in my homescreen class. This works. I have a second screen where I use the variable to initialize my list of items. Here a user can filter this activity list and based on the filter I remove items dynamically from the local list. Somehow my global variable mimics now the number of entries of this local list which I do not understand. Maybe its too early but not sure whats going on.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

activities = globals.GlobalVariables.globalActivities;
print("act list start: ${globals.GlobalVariables.globalActivities.length}");
// final activities = Provider.of<List<Activity>>(context) ?? [];

// MyUser user = Provider.of<MyUser>(context);


if(widget.typefilter == "Tunnel"){
  print("act list mid 0: ${globals.GlobalVariables.globalActivities.length}");
  activities.removeWhere((i){
    if (i.type == 'Other'){
      return true;
    }else{
      return false;
    }
  });
  print("act list mid 0b: ${globals.GlobalVariables.globalActivities.length}");
}else if (widget.typefilter == "Other"){
  activities.removeWhere((i){
    if (i.type == 'Tunnel'){
      return true;
    }else{
      return false;
    }
  });
}else{
  //nothing
}
print("act list mid 1: ${globals.GlobalVariables.globalActivities.length}");
```

The printlog logs like this:

```
flutter: act list start: 1978
flutter: act list mid 0: 1978
flutter: act list mid 0b: 0
flutter: act list mid 1: 0
flutter: act list end 0: 0
```

It is correct that the activities list should be 0 but why is my global list now 0 as well?

thanks,
timo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you initialize `activities` with `activities = globals.GlobalVariables.globalActivities;`, you aren't creating a new `List` but are creating an extra reference to the existing `List< Activity>`.

If you don't want changes to `activities` to reflect on `globalActivities`, you'll need to make a copy, for example with [List.of()](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-core/List/List.of.html):

```dart
List<Activity> activities = List.of(globals.GlobalVariables.globalActivities);
```

Note that this will be a *shallow clone*. You won't have a deep copy of the Activity inside, but it will again be a reference. This means that if you were to change something in the `Activity` object from one list, the same `Activity` object in the other list will have the same changes. This seems fine for your use case.

Comment: Thanks mate! Was not aware of that. Helped me a lot :)

Comment: Glad I could help, best of luck!

Comment: You should always prefer `List.of` or `.toList` to copy a `List`. `List.from` loses type information and must then perform runtime casts that otherwise would be unnecessary.  See: https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#dont-use-listfrom-unless-you-intend-to-change-the-type-of-the-result

Comment: Good point! I made an edit to suggest .of() instead